# About the Laurent Series of the WeierstrassP function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, elliptic-functions

Mathematica returns the following Laurent Series for the $\wp(z;(1,1+I))$ function

```
Series[WeierstrassP[z, WeierstrassInvariants[{1, 1 + I}]], {z, 0, 12}]
```

$$\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^8}{5120 \pi ^2}z^2 +\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{16}}{78643200 \pi ^4}z^6 +\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{24}}{2617245696000 \pi ^6}z^{10} +O\left(z^{13}\right)$$

that is no terms for $z^4, z^8$, etc.

According to https://dlmf.nist.gov/23.9

$$
\wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}c_n z^{2n-2}.
$$

that is including terms for $z^4, z^8$, etc.

Can you please explain the discrepancy? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. The period lattice $\,\{1,i\}\,$ is a square lattice and has extra symmetries. Same thing with $\,\{1,(1+\sqrt{-3})/2\}\,$.

Comment: Are you saying that the z^4 etc. are dropped because of the extra symmetries ?

Comment: I verified that it happens. I know the odd powers disappear due to the even'ness' of the function. Could you explain, in an answer, why this happens with {1,i} and {1,(1+$\sqrt{-3}$)/2}?

Comment: The MathWorld article [Weierstrass Elliptic Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassEllipticFunction.html) explicitly names special cases equianharmonic, lemniscate, and pseudolemniscate, where $g_2=0$ or $g_3=0$. This explains the missing powers. Try `Series[WeierstrassP[z, #], {z, 0, 12}] & /@ {{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}}`.

Comment: The answer lies (also) in Exercise 12 from Chapter 1 in 'Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory by T. Apostol' :-)